# Prevent CKEditor from removing invalid style declarations in style attributes

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

Is there any way to prevent `CKEditor` from removing broken/invalid style declarations from elements.

We have some users that have used invalid values for things like `margins`, `widths`, etc. Basically they leave out the unit of measurement of the value like the following example:

```
<p style="margin-left: 5; margin-top: 2; margin-bottom: 2">...</p>
```

`CKEditor` removes the incorrect declaration when switching from source view to design view. Is there any way to stop this?

I understand why it is removed, I agree with why it is removed however it has become a requirement to allow this. Basically we want `CKEditor` to leave as much of what a user enters untouched even if it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

As [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/what-is-ckeditor) describes `"It's a WYSIWYG editor, which means that the text being edited on it looks as similar as possible to the results users have when publishing it".`

I think it will be easier for you to just add a `class` to the element that you need to style and style it in your external `css` file.

If you got different contents with dirrefent styles you can do something like this

```
<div class="content1">        in your css         .content1 p{margin:2px 0px 2px 5px;}
<p>text goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understand the whole WYSIWYG principle and the need for accuracy in the results that are presented. I have attempted to explain how to fix this to the user, it's simple, just add 'px' behind the unit. However, we just recently switched editors to CKEditor and in the user's words "this wasn't a problem in the previous editor". CKEditor is way better but I want it to leave the invalid styles unfixed/un-removed. The other thing I should've mentioned is that this is for email so styles need to be inline